# Kubernetes kind : sudo kind delete cluster failed to lock config file: open /root/.kube/config.lock: read-only file system but no such file

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I'm testing k8s using kind.

I created cluster:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo kind get clusters
nodes-test
```

Now I like to delete this cluster with `sudo kind delete cluster` but getting:

```
Deleting cluster "kind" ...
failed to update kubeconfig: failed to lock config file: open /root/.kube/config.lock: read-only file system
ERROR: failed to delete cluster "kind": failed to lock config file: open /root/.kube/config.lock: read-only file system
```

But when going to the path I don't see the file:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo su
root@vagrant:/home/vagrant# cd /root
root@vagrant:~# cd .kube/
root@vagrant:~/.kube# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  8 12:07 .
drwx------ 6 root root 4096 Sep  8 12:26 ..
drwxr-x--- 4 root root 4096 Sep  8 12:00 cache
-rw------- 1 root root 5622 Sep  8 11:59 config
```

The config file:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ss==
    server: https://127.0.0.1:44155
  name: kind-nodes-test
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-nodes-test
    user: kind-nodes-test
  name: kind-nodes-test
current-context: kind-nodes-test
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-nodes-test
  user:
    client-certificate-data: sss
    client-key-data: sdasd=
```

```
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port   Peer Address:PortProcess
udp   UNCONN 0      0       127.0.0.53%lo:domain      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=10281,fd=13))
udp   UNCONN 0      0      10.0.2.15%eth0:bootpc      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("systemd-network",pid=10265,fd=18))
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096    127.0.0.53%lo:domain      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=10281,fd=14))
tcp   LISTEN 0      128           0.0.0.0:ssh         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=711,fd=3))
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096        127.0.0.1:44155       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1109,fd=4))
tcp   LISTEN 0      128              [::]:ssh            [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=711,fd=4))
```

### Update

Also when invoking the command `sudo kind delete cluster --name nodes-test` I'm getting:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo kind delete cluster --name nodes-test
Deleting cluster "nodes-test" ...
failed to update kubeconfig: failed to lock config file: open /root/.kube/config.lock: read-only file system
ERROR: failed to delete cluster "nodes-test": failed to delete nodes: command "docker rm -f -v nodes-test-worker nodes-test-control-plane" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: Error response from daemon: container 4cf8b399150fffb9899ff963adacd255fe3b0b7aebdf6feda11ea1646b541340: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem: unlinkat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ba0d047b313dabc396f61cf1f2b3086d5cad05372de37410326d81e02f6130b: read-only file system
Error response from daemon: container 8b2fa50dc006191add9b64e89b834a0c952344433e61d1b9795b5c2470bf3e05: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem: unlinkat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a35de9a7ad18fbf3358c0be3d01a51ba7c7558ed49242d659a0e365c58798ae: read-only file system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type the command to get your clusters, it lists the name of the clusters:

```
$ sudo kind get clusters
nodes-test
```

So your cluster name is `nodes-test`. But typing `sudo kind delete cluster` only tries to delete the default cluster name (which by default is named `kind`). This is also why the delete command says `Deleting cluster "kind" ...`. You need to run the delete command with the cluster name. You can even read this in [the documentation for the delete command](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#deleting-a-cluster)

> If the flag `--name` is not specified, kind will use the default cluster context name `kind` and delete that cluster.

> Note: By design, requesting to delete a cluster that does not exist will not return an error. This is intentional and is a means to have an idempotent way of cleaning up resources.

You need to specify your cluster name. Try this: `sudo kind delete cluster --name nodes-test`

Comment: sorry i updated my question , i did run the command

Comment: `read-only file system` is probably the issue. Check file permissions with `ls -lah` and I would recommend NOT running `kind` commands with `sudo`, you shouldn't need to. I'd recommend maybe just deleting `/root/.kube` and run it without sudo.